# How to sort number list on tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I just made the small game on Xcode, this is the leaderboard of the game. I used core data to save the score and show on the leaderboard. My question is how to sort the number for tableview, for example the serial number show as "14 7 9 7 9" should be fixed to "7 7 9 9 14".

Thanks a lot!

This is the image for my leaderboard UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4403l.jpg

SoreListViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "Score.h"

/*
 *  This class is the ViewController for the Score List
 *  Because the party list uses a UITableView this class
 *  subclasses UITableViewController so we can override
 *  some of the important methods.
 */

@interface ScoreListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

//This Mutable Array will store all the monsters that are added to the party
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Score* currentScore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* scoreList;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *scoreTableview;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *simpleList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *normalList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *hardList;

@end
```

SoreListViewController.m

```
#import "ScoreListViewController.h"

@interface ScoreListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ScoreListViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.scoreTableview.delegate = self;
    self.scoreTableview.dataSource = self;
    self.simpleList = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.normalList = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.hardList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self getScore];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



-(void)getScore
{
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Score"];

    NSError* error;
    self.scoreList= [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    //error log
    if(self.scoreList == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot fetch the list for your Scores:\n%@", error.userInfo);
    }

    for (id obj in self.scoreList) {
        Score *sc = (Score*)obj;
        int type = [sc.type intValue];
        if (type == 0) {
            [self.simpleList addObject:sc.score];
        }
        else if (type == 1) {
            [self.normalList addObject:sc.score];
        }
        else if (type == 2) {
            [self.hardList addObject:sc.score];
        }
    }
}


//Table view method, there is only 1 object be shown in storyabord
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

//Table view,return the number of the rows of data.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [self.simpleList count];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [self.normalList count];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [self.hardList count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return [self.scoreList count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Easy";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"Noramal";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"Hard";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *scoreCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"scoreCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.simpleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.normalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.hardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return scoreCell;
}




@end
```

Score.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Score : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * score;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;

@end
```

Score.m

```
#import "Score.h"


@implementation Score

@dynamic score;
@dynamic type;

@end
```

And here is the image for the core data model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhMlv.png

Thanks again, and really need you guys help T_T.

Comment: How are you feeding the `UITableView`. Simply sort your scores before feeding the table view.

Comment: Dear Zachary Chen, you added code samples with "code snipped" button, usually this button used for "runnable code" like javascript etc., probably you want  to use "code sample" button (which is curly braces button in editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Your GetScore Method  **Edit Check**

```
-(void)getScore
{
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Score"];

NSError* error;
self.scoreList= [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

//error log
if(self.scoreList == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot fetch the list for your Scores:\n%@", error.userInfo);
}

for (id obj in self.scoreList) {
    Score *sc = (Score*)obj;
    int type = [sc.type intValue];
    if (type == 0) {
        [self.simpleList addObject:sc.score];
    }
    else if (type == 1) {
        [self.normalList addObject:sc.score];
    }
    else if (type == 2) {
        [self.hardList addObject:sc.score];
    }
}


    [self.hardList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
  {

  NSNumber *num1=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj1.intValue];
  NSNumber *num2=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj2.intValue];
  return [num1 compare:num2];
    }];


   [self.normalList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
```

{
     NSNumber *num1=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj1.intValue];
      NSNumber *num2=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj2.intValue];
      return [num1 compare:num2];
    }];

```
[self.simpleList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
```

{
  NSNumber *num1=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj1.intValue];
  NSNumber *num2=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj2.intValue];
  return [num1 compare:num2];
}];

```
}
```

//Your TableView Method

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 3;
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return [self.simpleList count];
        break;
    case 1:
        return [self.normalList count];
        break;
    case 2:
        return [self.hardList count];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

return [self.scoreList count];
}


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *scoreCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"scoreCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.simpleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.normalList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 2:
        scoreCell.textLabel.text = [self.hardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    default:
        break;
     }
```

this are the followimg methods where u have to make changes

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80295/discussion-on-answer-by-muku-how-to-sort-number-list-on-tableview).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method is to sort your arrays using the following simple code after you create them. The table will then display in order.

```
[self.simpleList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) 
{
  NSNumber *num1=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj1.intValue];
  NSNumber *num2=[NSNumber numberWithInt:obj2.intValue];
  return [num1 compare:num2];
}];
```

Do the same for your 2 other arrays.

You will have to adjust the string conversion to integer if you use large numbers.

Comment: Thx for your help to give the idea about number sorting.